# Retrieve session value and pass to an entity attribute

Tags: symfony

I want to retrieve a quantity for each item that I store in session and store it in database.

How do I retrieve the quantity in session and passed to my quantity attribute of my article entity during database persistence?

For example for this article:

[image]

(id 4, quantity 2).
I would store **2** in the quantity attribute of my article entity. 
I tried :

```
$article->setQuantity($session->get('panier'));
```

I have this error:

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO article ....... **{"4": "2"}**
Notice: Array to string conversion

```
  /**
     * @Route("/payment", name="payment")
     */
    public function paymentAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $produits = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Stock')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier')));

        $commande = $session->get('commande');

        var_dump($session->get('panier'));

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $token = $request->get('stripeToken');

            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($this->getParameter("private_key"));

            \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => $commande->getTotal() * 100,
                "currency" => "EUR",
                "source" => $token,
                "description" => ""
            ));

            foreach ($produits as $produit) {

                $article = new Article();
                $article->setTitle($produit->getStock()->getTitle());
                $article->setContent($produit->getStock()->getContent());
                //problem here
                $article->setQuantity($session->get('panier'));
                //
                $article->setPrice($produit->getPrice());

                $commande->addArticle($article);

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($commande);
                $em->flush();
            }

            return $this->redirectToRoute('confirmation');

        }
        return $this->render(':default:payment.html.twig', array(
            'commande' => $commande,
            'panier' => $session->get('panier'),
            'produits' => $produits,
            'public_key' => $this->getParameter("public_key"),
        ));
    }
```

Add article in session :

```
/**
 * @Route("/shop/add/{id}", name="add_article")
 *
 */
public function addArticlelAction(Request $request, $id)
{

    $session = $request->getSession();

    if (!$session->has('panier'))
        $session->set('panier', array());
    $panier = $session->get('panier');

    if (array_key_exists($id, $panier)) {
        if ($request->query->get('qte') != null)
            $panier[$id] = $request->query->get('qte');
    } else {
        if ($request->query->get('qte') != null)
            $panier[$id] = $request->query->get('qte');
        else
            $panier[$id] = 1;

    }

    $session->set('panier', $panier);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('panier');
}
```

Comment: how do you set the panier in the session ?

Comment: $session->get('panier') contains an array of your articles right ? No just a quantity ?

Comment: Yes it contains an array of articles. I try to access the quantity from the session by putting [0], [1].... but it does not work

Comment: Can we see the code where you store panier in session, to be sure ?

Comment: I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: 
If `$id` in `addArticlelAction` is the product id then:

```
    foreach ($produits as $produit) {

                $article = new Article();
                $article->setTitle($produit->getStock()->getTitle());
                $article->setContent($produit->getStock()->getContent());
                //problem here
                $article->setQuantity($session->get('panier')[$produit->getId()]);
                //
                $article->setPrice($produit->getPrice());

                $commande->addArticle($article);

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($commande);
                $em->flush();
            }
```

should work, because for the moment you have two products (product1 who has id 1 and product 4 who has id 4). When you call /shop/add/{id}, you are adding to `$session->get('panier')[1]` and `$session->get('panier')[4]` the quantities. So, when you're in foreach (to store in DB), you need to access index 1 and index 4 (`$produit->getId()`)

Comment: Now I have no error message but the quantity field remains null in bdd.

Comment: Are you sure that `$request->query->get('qte')` is not null ? Try to dump

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($session->get('panier'));` ?

Comment: yes it is not null, I test by adding 2 items : 
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=781094test.jpg

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump of `$produits` please ?

Comment: I change the value of the quantity attribute in my entity to nullable = false,
I have the quantity in the var_dump but it wants to persist to "null"
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=255904error.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150104/discussion-between-quentin-lerebours-and-chk35).